# How to use changefeed inside a botapp to refresh the cache on change in cosmos db container?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, botframework, azure-webapps, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I have a botapp hosted in Azure, using cosmos db table1 (Example name) needs to cached in bot app. Since cosmos db is accessible from another app as well, which is a web app and users can update the data in table1 through this webapp.

So the requirement here is whenever someone update the data in table1 from webapp, the cache inside the botapp needs to be refreshed.

PS : Both app are sharing the same database.

I have tried ChangefeedProcessor but it needs to be hosted outside the bot app and then to trigger the refresh cache inside the bot app, i have to expose an endpoint which i don't want.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor

If anyone can suggest a way to use/host the changefeedprocessor inside the same botapp, would be a great help here OR another way to refresh cache.